# Can't use domain name to access mail server from outside LAN

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, local-area-network, mx-record, citadel

Thanks for the assistance with my last post, it was able to work itself out nicely. Now I have another issue...

I have got an A DNS record setup pointing mail.melia.tech to my public IP address

I have got an MX DNS record setup pointing melia.tech to mail.melia.tech (so I can receive emails to addresses of the form user@melia.tech).

From within the LAN, I can use mail.melia.tech with Thunderbird as well as typing into my browser to access the Citadel Web Interface. I have got ports 80, 110 and 25 forwarded to the internal ip of my server.

I am having trouble accessing this mail server from outside my LAN though. I can't access the server using mail.melia.tech. I can only use my public IP address!

If I want to access the Citadel interface from my phone for example, on a mobile data network, I need to use the public IP in Safari, and as the incoming and outgoing mail server in the Mail app. If I try to use the domain name, I am told by safari that the server does not exist.

I appreciate help in advance, please let me know if there's any more info required or if my post could be changed to make a solution easier to come by.

Comment: Unfortunately, your description of the problem consists exclusively of the words "I have trouble". But you don't tell us precisely what you tried and precisely what went wrong, which makes it hard for us to help. I can reach your mail server as `mail.melia.tech` just fine.

Comment: The DNS server you are using on you phone, must have cache the negative resolution result before you added the records.

Comment: Thanks David. I’ll give you a better description. When I type “mail.melia.tech” into any browser connected to my LAN, I reach my Citadel server login page. When I type “mail.melia.tech” into my iPhone using a cellular data connection, I reach a safari page saying “Safari can not open the page because the server could not be found”. My question is, is this an issue with how my DNS is set up or is this a characteristic of mobile networks? EDIT: I haven’t tried connecting from another non-mobile device (ie one connected to a different wifi network or LAN) so haven’t been able to test that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it was just a time thing or whether my tinkering did the trick - it seems to be working now. I can point my phone to my domain name from outside my LAN and access my mail server.

I went into my router settings and fixed up the IP filtering - it worked shortly after this.

Thanks for the help!